# How to include config files when deploying to Vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I have a NextJS project I want to deploy to Vercel. The server needs a config file which is a typescript file containing an object, and is ignored from version control. Obviously when Vercel clones my repo it doesn't get the config file. Is there any way to sideload this config file into Vercel or do I need to fork my own repo privately so I can include the config file?

Comment: check your .gitignore file. The file (or path) is probably excluded

Comment: The best way to do configs is to create an .env (or .env-local) file and then set the config files in Vercel as well.

Comment: @JoelHager it is excluded. That's intentional. I'm trying to ask if there's any way I can load the file in after Vercel clones the repo?

Comment: Ah. I must've misread. You should look into environment variables with Vercel: https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables

Comment: @JoelHager Yes I'm aware of the environmental variables. This file is not an env file. It's a typescript file, it's code. I need to include another code file that I can't have in version control

Comment: Why does a TS file have to be excluded from the repo?

Comment: @JoelHager because it's a config file. It's a config file that's in typescript code

Comment: I've never experienced anybody using a private `file` over private vars. For instance - You make the config file public, but the values are env vars. That's normally how I see it used. I even looked at the docs and couldn't see anything that would align with what you're looking for. :/

Comment: https://vercel.com/storage/edge-config

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and the only faster way I found is to push directly to Vercel using the cmd/cli.

Here's the doc: https://vercel.com/docs/cli

Another way could be to create two repositories, one private where is your Vercel project linked, and another public without your config file (as you said).